# Where can I get Linq for NHibernate?

Tags: .net, linq, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

Where can I get the current Linq provider for NHibernate? I am also using the [current release of Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) (1.1). Will the current Linq provider (once I find it) play nicely with fluent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/

Answer (score 1):

You can find the current linq provider in the trunk of the [NHibernate subversion repository][1].

[1]: https://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhibernate nhibernate

The linq provider will play nicely with Fleunt, because FluentNH does not have influence on it. The only think FluentNH does, is providing a .Net syntax that will be converted to the original XML mappings. FluentNH feeds NH xml mappings.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from here: [NHibernate](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/). The current, non-alpha release of LINQ for NHIbernate [is here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/2.1.2GA/NHibernate.Linq-2.1.2-GA-Bin.zip/download). I hear, that LINQ support is much improved in 3.0, but it is still in Alpha - but you could consider using it, depending on the nature of your project.

LINQ for NHIbernate will play nicely with Fluent. LINQ is for querying, Fluent is for configuration, so they won't step on each others toes.

Comment: This is not the current, but the previous linq provider

Comment: @Paco, depends on what is meant by "Current". I link to the latest released version (ie. non-alpha).

Comment: I don't know why it technically matters that it's called alpha. There are only political reasons to use the old version for the new project. Alpha does not mean unstable.

Comment: Alpha doesn't necessarily mean stable, either, whereas RTM does.

Comment: The code in the NHiberante trunk, or in the alpha binary release is more stable or unstable than a RTM version.

Answer (score 0):

Fluent 1.1 works nicely with this current version of NHibernate.Linq (for NHibernate 2.1.2.400):

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/2.1.2GA/NHibernate.Linq-2.1.2-GA-Bin.zip/download

We use this combination at work and they play together nicely.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use LINQ with NHibernate/Fluent NHibernate you need to use NHibernate 3.0. Since the current version of Fluent NHibernate builds with NHibernate v2.0 you will need to do a custom build of Fluent NHibernate with NHibernate v3.0.

Here is a [blog article](http://theminimalistdeveloper.com/2010/11/20/how-to-use-fluent-nhibernate-linq-and-sqlite-in-asp-net-mvc-3-project/) that might be of some help to you.